# Add a column of one data frame to a column of another similar data frame

Tags: r

I have 2 data.frames similar to this one below:

```
df1
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10

df2
   x y
1  6 1
2  7 2
3  8 3
4  9 4
5 10 5
```

I want to add the column 'x' of the first data.frame to the column 'x' of the second data.frame (same operation for column 'y' also) to get a new data.frame like this:

```
df
       x y
    1  7 7
    2  9 9
    3  11 11
    4  13 13
    5  15 15
```

Say, I have more than 2 data.frames with more than 2 columns in each data.frame. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! ... So this is about computing sums? To me, the title of the question was slightly misleading, I first thought you wanted to *append* a column...

Comment: Thanks! Sorry.. I'm still a noob :(

Answer (score 2):

You just plus them together since they only contain numbers

```
df1+df2
```

edit: for a lot of data.frames in a list, call that list `x`:

```
Reduce("+", x)
```

Comment: Sometimes life can be so simple ;-)

Comment: Thanks JeremyS! 
But I have more than 2.. around 15 in a list. Can I use a loop to sum all of them?